# Não realiza download da planilha XLS

Tags: php, xls

O sistema estava em uma revenda e tive que migrar para uma VPS com Cpanel, o script para gerar o XLS estava funcionando certinho, abria e realizava o download , porem agora ele apenas abre na tela

O que preciso ativar para que funcione corretamente?

---

```
$html = '<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Coluna 1</td>        
        <td>Coluna 2</td>        
        <td>Coluna 2</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Coluna 1</td>        
        <td>Coluna 2</td>        
        <td>Coluna 2</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Coluna 1</td>        
        <td>Coluna 2</td>        
        <td>Coluna 2</td>        
    </tr>
</table>';

// Configurações header para forçar o download
header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"nome_arquivo.xls\"" );
header ("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data" );

echo $html;
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido!

Tinha que ativar o **output_buffering** no PHP.INI

Feito isso, problema resolvido!